# Back Propagation Algorithm is not working properly

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation

I am new to Neural Networks.I was trying to write simple 4-0-2 MLP and learn back-propagation algorithm in practice. But my back-propagation always diverges and the output is always [1,1]. I searched for the possible cause but neither setting learning rate to quite small number(0.001) nor changing the sign of delta weight could solve the problem.

**Code for back-propagation algorithm:**

```
def backward(self,trainingSamples):
    for i in range(len(trainingSamples)):
        curr_sample=trainingSamples[i]
        self.input=curr_sample[0]
        self.forward()
        print("output is "+str(self.output))
        curr_des_out=curr_sample[1]
        for i in range(len(self.outputs)):
            error=curr_des_out[i]-self.outputs[i].output
            der_act=self.outputs[i].activate(deriv=True)
            local_gradient=der_act*error
            for j in range(len(self.input)):
                self.weights[j][i]-=self.learning_rate*local_gradient*self.input[j]
```

and `trainingSamples` is a tuple of tuples of arrays:`( ([1,1,1,1],[1,0]), ([0,0,0,0],[0,1]),([1,0,0,0],[0,1]), ([1,0,1,0],[1,0]) )`

Here is the forward pass code:

```
def forward(self):
    for i in range(len(self.outputs)):
        for j in range(len(self.input)):
            self.outputs[i].input+=self.input[j]*self.weights[j][i]
        self.outputs[i].activate()
        self.output[i]=self.outputs[i].output
    return self.output
```

Comment: Can you show how you calculate the output? Perhaps there is something wrong with the forward (as well)? (I don't want to offend you, but the more we can exclude, the better I think).

Comment: @david_l: perhaps you better [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41837181/edit) it in your question.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem,done

Comment: Are you sure you "reset" (set to `0`) you `output[i].inputs` before you call? Because here you keep adding up.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem,outputs is an arrray of output neurons,and their input is equal to the network input,`cos there is no hidden layer,so it is changing with every call.

Comment: @david_l: no but you call the `forward` each time and in your forward algorithm you iterate over all "neurons" to feed them with input, but forget to first reset the input. Unless you do this in your activate function, you will thus "add up" the inputs of previous sessions.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem,I finally get it.

Comment: Kinda unrelated, but you may want to look into linear algebra and try a matrix-based implementation based on numpy. It is much less bug-prone and more efficient. The deep learning book by Goodfellow, Bengio and Courville is pretty great.

Comment: @MartinKrämer,I'll go and check it out immediately.Thanks for advice!

Comment: @david_I Welcome. BTW here is a matrix-based MLP implementation using numpy I wrote recently, if you want to reference some code without tons of library bloat: https://github.com/mkraemer67/nn-experiments/blob/master/nn_from_scratch/neural%20nets%20from%20scratch.ipynb It's not super-optimized, but pretty easy to read.

Comment: @MatrinKrämer,thanks for that!I was looking for simple,but complete neural network implementation for quite a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Althoug I cannot see the full implementation of your code (things like `.activate()`, etc. I think I have an idea how you have implemented them. Given you have implemented them correctly I see one problem with your code that will clearly show divergence.

The problem - or at least one of the problems - seems to be that you do not reset the input (dendrite) of your neurons:

```
def forward(self):
    for i in range(len(self.outputs)):
        self.outputs[i].input = 0
        for j in range(len(self.input)):
            self.outputs[i].input+=self.input[j]*self.weights[j][i]
        self.outputs[i].activate()
        self.output[i]=self.outputs[i].output
    return self.output
```

Because you keep incrementing the input, I suspect that indeed you eventually end up with output `[1,1]` since the sigmoid function goes to 1 as its input goes to infinity.

Comment: I use sigmoid as activation function.

Comment: @david_I: yes but I assume the sigmoid does not clear the input of the session?

Comment: if w and x shape are different(like conv layer or other layer), thus dw and dx shape are different, how can we element-wise top-layer's dx multiply by the previous-layer's dw that affect the change of w of this previous layer.